# Get posts sharing taxonomy term with current post's

Tags: loop, taxonomy

I have a post and I want to get a loop with a list of all other pages, which are in the same taxonomy/taxonomy-categorie. Right now, I'm only able to insert the taxonomy name by myself. I think it should be the same way like asking for the current post type.

Here is my array:

```
$post_type = get_post_type( $post->ID );
$args = array( 'post_type' => $post_type, 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy category',);
```

Thank you!